# Validate json file for correct format

Tags: blazor

I need to validate if the selected Json file is valid (if in correct format). As some are missing closing bracket ']' at the end of file. How can I include validation here. I couldn't find a proper documentation that does this. Thank you.

```
    _loadedFile = e.File;       
    var utf8Json = _loadedFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10); 
    var jsonDocument = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(utf8Json);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `TryParseValue` can be used in your case

Otherwise you can use `try/catch` on `JsonException`.

[Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument.parseasync?view=net-7.0).